# Liferay autentication web service

Tags: web-services, authentication, liferay, single-sign-on

I'm new in Liferay.
I want to use Liferay as my backend and I have several web services to interact with it.
Where can I find documentation (or some example) to provide a web service to use for authentication liferay user?
This is just to get started and to get familiar with, the instrument. Then I must integrate a single sign-on system in this web service.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I believe chapters 11 and 12 of the [developer's guide](https://www.liferay.com/documentation/liferay-portal/6.1/development/-/ai/liferay-portal-6-1-development-guide) might contain some valuable information. With regards to signing in - and as you already mention SSO - I'd recommend to authenticate to a common backend rather than to Liferay directly. Liferay supports several SSO systems out-of-the-box. Liferay's Webservices are generated through ServiceBuilder (read that chapter as well), and you'll recognize them by their names - e.g. UserService is the remote service handling user management (UserLocalService is the one that's not remotely available, servicebuilder documentation will teach you about the various postfixes to these names, like *Util, *Impl etc.)

Also, with questions like your's I'm never completely sure which Webservice is using what infrastructure: If you write portlets in Liferay that consume external Webservices this is a different story than you writing webservices that delegate some action to Liferay's Webservices. Both are possible (of course), but ask for a different approach: You'll have to make Liferay's services available (through configuration, by default they're only available to 127.0.0.1), but you can consume any WebService you like from your plugins, without Liferay having anything to say in it.

Only when you want to publish your plugins on the marketplace, you'll need to declare where you want to connect to - thus you'd have to read about PACL in this case.

Answer (score 0):

you can find steps by steps tutorial for web service.
http://www.liferaysavvy.com/2014/05/consuming-liferay-json-web-services.html

You can call web service with help of Java script like below with authentication.

```
<script>
$(document).on('ready',function(){ 
            var username ="test@liferay.com";
            var password ="test"; 
            function make_base_auth(user, password) {
              var tok = user + ':' + password;
              var hash = btoa(tok);
              return "Basic " + hash;
            }
                $.ajax({
                  url: 'http://localhost:8080/api/jsonws/CustomJsonWebservices-portlet.employee/get-employee/emplyee-id/1',
                  dataType: "json",
                  type: "get",
                  success: function(data){
                          alert('Employee Data with Id 1 is');       
                          alert(data.emplyeeName);
                          alert(data.employeeDesignation);
                  },
                  beforeSend: function(xhr){
                          xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization',make_base_auth(username, password));
                                    },
                                    complete: function(){
                                    },
                  error: function(){
                  }
                });

 });
</script>
```

You can find complete code below for web service.
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B9B1NsG0lyx6Q2dlUVp6LU5fX0E/view?usp=sharing